# Creating sound bars with jQuery and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have am trying to create animated soundbars using jquery (js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rhK4n/ )

HTML

```
<div class="eq">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bar {
    background-color: green;
    width:15px;
    height:40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

jQuery

```
function fluctuate(bar) {
    var hgt = Math.random() * 10;
    hgt += 1;
    var t = hgt * 30;

    bar.animate({
        height: hgt
    }, t, function() {
        fluctuate($(this));
    });
}

$(".bar").each(function(i) {
    fluctuate($(this));
});
```

I want the soundbars to be 40px in height.

However, this method contracts them to c.15px and so the baseline moves up and down, **I want it to be fixed**.

I can't figure out why this error is occuring.

Comment: Seems to me CSS3 animations would help in this situation

Comment: I am using jQuery for XB compatability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the baseline from moving up and down you'll need to do some different things with the CSS.  There might be several possible solutions, here is one.

http://jsfiddle.net/rhK4n/6/

Basically CSS always work from the top-line vs. the baseline.  But using absolute positioning you can 'sink' the soundbars to the bottom of the `.eq` div.  You then have to space the bars out separately but I think this will give you results closer to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, you are returning a height that is an integer in the range [0,1), and then adding 1 to the value. Then you scale the value by 30. You should be returning a random integer between the range [0,40) like so:

```
var amplitude = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 1;
```

So your code could look like this:

```
function fluctuate(bar) {
    var height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 1;
    //Animate the equalizer bar repeatedly
    bar.animate({
        height: height
    }, function() {
        fluctuate($(this));
    });
}

$(".bar").each(function(i) {
    fluctuate($(this));
});
```

Or, if you need floating-point values, use:

```
var height = (Math.random() * (40.000)).toFixed(4)
```

**EDIT**: Here's a functioning jsFiddle that shows how you could handle the baseline problem: http://jsfiddle.net/3mhJJ/. This solution does *not* require you to individually space out each equalizer bar.

Comment: Interesting, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rhK4n/2/ Problem is as per @robert's comment; the baseline moves up and down.

Comment: Yes, but I thought that side-effect was outside of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example without javascript, only css.

Please check out this [pen](https://codepen.io/zalog/pen/GWQjKr) and the sass css:

```
$bars-number: 40; // this must reflect markup changes in html too
$bar-color: blue;

.animate-bars {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lighten($bar-color, 45%);

  div {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 -2px;
    background-color: $bar-color;
    animation: animate-bar 300ms linear infinite alternate;
    transform-origin: bottom;
    opacity: 0;

    &:first-child {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    &:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }

    @for $i from 1 to $bars-number + 1 {
      &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        animation-duration: (350 + random(450)) + ms;
        animation-delay: random(500) + ms;
      }
    }
  }
}

@keyframes animate-bar {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0);
    opacity: .8;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(100%);
    opacity: .4;
  }
}
```